# Understanding word placement in German

Tags: word-order

I am confused as to the placement of “noch” in the sentence : “Aber ich will noch nicht schlafen”. I’m aware the whole sentence means “but I don’t want to sleep yet” but putting “noch” in the middle confuses me as I don’t know the rule(s) as to why it is there, rather than the end of the sentence like it is in English.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Adverbial placement in German can be tricky.

> Am Sonntag trifft sie ihre Freundin.
>
> Sie trifft am Sonntag ihre Freundin.
>
> Sie trifft ihre Freundin am Sonntag.

These are all common. The difference is in the emphasis. The first item in the sentence gets most emphasis, the last second most.

> Noch haben wir Zeit.
>
> Wir haben noch Zeit.
>
> <s>Wir haben Zeit noch.</s>

Most of those one-word adverbials cannot go to the end of such a short sentence. You can heal that, however:

> Wir haben **die** Zeit noch.

That erratic feature of German seems more connected to rhythm than anything else. It also appears with lone pronouns at the end of the sentence.

---

Your example uses a modal verb phrase as the predicate, and those occupy the end of the sentence with their infinitive part already. This gives you the only options *front* and *middle* in any case.

> Aber ich will noch nicht schlafen.
>
> Aber noch will ich nicht schlafen.
>
> Aber ich will am Sonntag nicht schlafen.
>
> Aber am Sonntag will ich nicht schlafen.